# Get calling action and action's arguments from Hibernate Event listener in Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy

I would like to create custom annotation for my domain classes in Grails for auditing. I'm thinking about listening to hibernate events and then save those annotated classes actions.

I still have problem with how could I get the action that called this domain class method and what was its arguments? How could I got them? Any ideas?

Thanks,
Feras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [RequestContextHolder](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.html) to access the current [GrailsWebRequest](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/servlet/mvc/GrailsWebRequest.html)

```
GrailsWebRequest req = (GrailsWebRequest)RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
if(req != null) {
  log.info("controller = " + req.getControllerName());
} else {
  log.info("Not in a web request thread");
}
```

You also have `req.getParams()` if you need the whole parameter map.